# In C, why is an array reference a += 2; invalid code

Tags: c, arrays

From my lecture slides, it states:

As illustrated in the code below an array name can be assigned
to an appropriate pointer without the need for a preceding & operator.

```
int x;  
int a[3] = {0,1,2};  
int *pa = a;  
x = *pa;  
x = *(pa + 1);  
x = *(pa + 2);  
a += 2; /* invalid */
```

Why is `a += 2;` invalid?

Can anyone help clarify?
Also feel free to edit the title if you think of a better one.

Comment: Thanks Peter, i should have noticed the code block function.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pointer arithmetic and arrays: what's really legal?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2383837/pointer-arithmetic-and-arrays-whats-really-legal), [Are pointers and arrays any different in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054247/are-pointers-and-arrays-any-different-in-c), and more.

Comment: sorry, I had no idea for what search terms to use.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`a += 2` gets translated to `a = a + 2`. Adding a number to an array is the same as adding a number to a pointer which is valid and yields a new pointer.

The assignment is the problem - arrays are not lvalues, so you cannot assign anything to them. It is just not allowed. And even if you could there is a type mismatch here - you’re trying to assign a pointer to an array which does not make sense.

Comment: Thankyou, you have answered my question clearly and precisely.
However I now wish I remembered/(was taught) what lvalues were.
I believe my confusion was that arrays were pointers to the first value.

Comment: A lvalue basically is something that can be on the left side of an assignment statement (l for left). So basically variables (except arrays), pointer dereferences (*ptr), array element access (array[index]) and struct field access (str.field or ptr->field) are lvalues.

Comment: @Sven: Actually it is an lvalue, but one that you can't assign to. 6.3.2.1/1, "A modiﬁable lvalue is an lvalue that does not have array type, does not have an incomplete type, does not have a const-qualiﬁed type, and if it is a structure or union, does not have any member (including, recursively, any member or element of
all contained aggregates or unions) with a const-qualiﬁed type". Arguably, the term "lvalue" is therefore misleading terminology, since there are lvalues which cannot be the lhs of an assignment. C++0x "clarifies" the issue by introducing several new kinds of expression ;-)

Comment: @Steve: Didn’t know that either. So I should have written "modifiable lvalue" and everything was right.

Comment: @Sven: yes, I agree with everything else you say.

Comment: @Ryan The Leach: Arrays *aren't* pointers, but it often looks as if they are, because in almost all contexts they are evaluated as a pointer to their first element.

Answer (score 7):

`a += 2;` is invalid because `+=` operator isn't defined for arrays. Furthermore arrays are non modifiable `lvalues` so you cannot assign to them.

Answer (score 2):

When you pass a to a function where a pointer is expected, the address of a is used. This leads to the wrong statement, an array and a pointer are interchangeable.

But

- a is an array
- pa is a pointer

Since pa is a scalar, you can modify it with

```
pa = pa + 2;
```

or

```
pa += 2;
```

The array a does not define any operation like

```
a = a + 2;  /* invalid */
```

Answer (score 0):

when you write a += 2 then it translated to a = a + 2.

So it means you modify base address of array.
That is not allow in c because if you modify base address of array then how you access array element.

It will give Lvalue required error at compile time.