# Whats the difference? Pointer to an array vs regular array

Tags: c++, c

I'm familiar with Java and trying to teach myself C/C++. I'm stealing some curriculum from a class that is hosting their materials [here](http://courses.washington.edu/css342/zander/css332/array.html). I unfortunately can't ask the teacher since I'm not in the class. My concern is with the section under "dynamically declared arrays":

> If you
>   want to be able to alter the size of
>   your array at run time, then declare
>   dynamic arrays. These are done with
>   pointers and the new operator. For the
>   basics on pointers, read the pointers
>   section.
>
> Allocate memory using new, and then
>   you access the array in the same way
>   you would a static array. For example,
>
> int* arrayPtr = new int[10];    for
>   (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
>         arrayPtr[i] = i;    }
>
> The memory picture is identical to the
>   static array, but you can change the
>   size if you need to. Don't forget you
>   must deallocate the memory before
>   allocating new memory (or you will
>   have a memory leak).
>
> delete [] arrayPtr;      // the []
>   is needed when deleting array pointers
>   arrayPtr = new int[50];    . . .
>
> When you're completely done with the
>   array, you must delete its memory:
>
> delete [] arrayPtr;
>
> Dynamic multi-dimensional arrays are
>   done in a similar manner to Java. You
>   will have pointers to pointers. For an
>   example, see a

My understanding is that an array in C is simply a reference to the memory address of the first element in the array.

So, what is the difference between `int *pointerArray = new int[10];` and `int array[10];` if any?

I've done some tests that seem to indicate that they do the exact same thing. Is the website wrong or did I read that wrong?

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    // Initialize the pointer array
    int *pointerArray = new int[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){

        pointerArray[i] = i;
    }

    // Initialize the regular array
    int array[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){

        array[i]= i;
    }

    cout << *(pointerArray + 5) << endl;
    cout << *(array + 5) << endl;

    cout << pointerArray[5] << endl;
    cout << array[5] << endl;

    cout << pointerArray << endl;
    cout << array << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
5
5
5
5
0x8f94030
0xbfa6a37c
```

I've tried to "dynamically re-size" my pointer array as described on the site, but my new (bigger) pointer array ends up filled with 0's which is not very useful.

Comment: pointerArray + 5 - it is wrong because of the size of int is more then one byte

Comment: are you sure there is no typo in the code? It seems to me that the results of the first 4 `cout` statements should all be 5.

Comment: @Ivan: No, that is perfect. In pointer arithmetic, the size of the data type that the pointer points to is available internally. So, pointerArray + 5 will increment by 5*sizeof(int), i.e, it will give you the 5th element of the array that pointerArray points to.

Comment: @Ivan: why should it be wrong ? When performing arithmetic on a pointer `T*`, `+ 5` means `+ 5 * sizeof(T)`.

Comment: @James T: Consider using `std::vector<int>` if you can, much much easier.

Comment: It is mentioned in the quoted text but still you forgot to release your memory with `delete[] pointerArray`.

Comment: Urgh, that's not C++, it's torture. In C++, we have the `vector` class for dynamic arrays. There is a school of thought which believes that the goal when teaching C++ is to maximize the number of bugs the students can make afterwards, by teaching them only the worst way to do everything. Since the material you found follows this philosophy, the best you can do if you want to learn C++ is run away screaming. Then buy a book on C++

Comment: @Sriram your right there is a typo, just re-ran the code

Comment: I just don't understand why these tutorials are hell bent on spoiling the image of C++. In C++ a much better alternative of `std::vector` is available, still they talk about creating dynamic arrays using `new[]`.

Comment: I think that is a legit question. @James T is a newbie to C/C++ and is learning. The question is also marked as homework.

Comment: @Sriram: it's not the legitimacy of the question we're questioning. We're saying that the teaching material he found *sucks*, and is going to waste his time and require him to re-learn a lot of things *properly* afterwards.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pointer vs array in C, non-trivial difference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/660752/pointer-vs-array-in-c-non-trivial-difference)

Comment: @jalf One of the things I find exciting about C++ is that I can deal with memory directly. Having everything abstracted to things like vectors is very useful, but does not help my ultimate goal of understanding how everything works on a low level. I'm using C++ as a middle ground before I tackle assembly. So yes, this kind of stuff might discourage some, but for me, its the reason I'm learning C++. It depends on the audience. Maybe I can disassemble C++ to get some almost-readable assembly.

Comment: @James: it's not about discouraging you, it is about teaching things in a sensible order. I'm not saying you shouldn't learn to deal with manual memory management, just that it shouldn't be taught until the student has a good grasp of many other fundamentals in the language. C++ is a complex language, and regardless of what you want to use it for, you need to build up the right mental models of how it works, and how it should be used. Unfortunately, many teachers think of it as "C with extras"

Comment: @jalf Ah ok. The website was intended to introduce a student who has an understanding of Java into the world of C++. From what I understand, Java is based on C++. Maybe those fundamental concepts of C++ are assumed to have been taught in Java? In any case, I'll try to find a good book on C++ as you suggested. Thanks for the advice!

Comment: @James: that depends on how you define it. I'd say Java and C++ are both based on the notion of "C with classes". And one of the things that often trip Java programmers up is the assumption that this means that C++ can be thought of as a direct predecessor of Java. It's not (if in doubt, consider that Java 1.0 came out in 1995, while C++ was standardized in late 1998). IOW. some of the early work on C++ clearly influenced Java, but most of what defines C++ today came later, and thus had no bearing on Java. Think of them as sibling languages (with a common ancestor) instead

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`int array[10];` declares the array size statically, that means it is fixed - which is the only major difference. It also might be allocated to be inside the function's stack frame, i.e. on the program's stack. You do not need to worry about using `delete []` on that kind of array, in fact, you might crash the program if you `delete` it.

When you use `operator new`, you allocate memory dynamically which could be *slower* and the memory usually comes from the *heap* rather than the program's stack (though not always). This is better in most cases, as you are more limited in the stack space than the heap space. However, you must watch out for memory leaks and `delete[]` your stuff when you don't need it anymore.

As to your array being filled with zeros, what your class material does not say is that you have to do this:

```
int *arr = new int[20]; // old array
//do magic here and decide that we need a bigger array
int *bigger = new int[50]; // allocate a bigger array
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) bigger[i] = arr[i]; // copy the elements from the old array into the new array
delete[] arr;
arr = bigger;
```

That code extends the array `arr` by 30 more elements. Note that you must copy the old data into the new array, or else it will not be there (in your case, everything becomes 0).

Comment: So the magic part here is the "arr = bigger;"? Otherwise I could just copy everything to bigger and use bigger instead of arr (if not using pointers).

Comment: Otherwise everything is crystal clear. Excellent answer. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, the magic part is the pointer reassingment. You can use the old name with a bigger size!

Comment: The code in the answer is missing initialization of the array data. Elements from `bigger[20]` to `bigger[49]` are uninitialized and will contain random values. To solve the issue you should use: `bigger = new int[50]();` (Note the extra parenthesis), and for an stack allocated array: `int initialized[20] = {};`

Answer (score 10):

> My understanding is that an array in C is simply a reference to the memory address of the first element in the array.
>
> So, what is the difference between int *pointerArray = new int[10]; and int array[10]; if any?

What you mention is the reason for much confusion in any C/C++ beginner.

In C/C++, an array corresponds to a block of memory sufficiently large to hold all of its elements. This is associated to the `[]` syntax, like in your example:

```
int array[10];
```

One feature of C/C++ is that you can refer to an array by using a pointer to its type. For this reason, you are allowed to write:

```
int* array_pointer = array;
```

which is the same as:

```
int* array_pointer = &array[0];
```

and this allows to access array elements in the usual way: `array_pointer[3]`,
but you cannot treat `array` as a pointer, like doing pointer arithmetics on it (i.e., array++ miserably fails).

That said, it is also true that you can manage arrays without using the `[]` syntax at all and just allocate arrays by using `malloc` and then using them with raw pointers. This makes the "beauty" of C/C++.

Resuming: a distinction must be made between the pointer and the memory that it points to (the actual array):

1. the `[]` syntax in declarations (i.e., `int array[10];`) refers to both aspects at once (it gives you, as to say, a pointer and an array);
2. when declaring a pointer variable (i.e., `int* p;`), you just get the pointer;
3. when evaluating an expression (i.e., `int i = p[4];`, or `array[4];`), the `[]` just means dereferencing a pointer.

Apart from this, the only difference between `int *pointerArray = new int[10];` and `int array[10];` is that former is allocated dynamically, the latter on the stack.

Comment: What is the difference between int *a  , and int *a[10]

Comment: @SurajJain `int *a` is a pointer to an int, whereas `int *a[10]` is an array (of size 10) of pointers to int.

Answer (score 3):

Dynamically allocated:

```
int * pointerArray = new int[10];
```

[BTW, this is a pointer to an array of 10 ints, NOT a pointer array]

Statically allocated (possibly on the stack):

```
int array[10];
```

Otherwise they are the same.

Answer (score 3):

The problem with understanding C/C++ arrays when coming from Java is that C/C++ distinguishes between the array variable and the memory used to store the array contents. Both concepts are important and distinct. In Java, you really just have a reference to an object that is an array.

You also need to understand that C/C++ has two ways of allocating memory. Memory can be allocated on the help or the stack. Java doesn't have this distinction.

In C and C++, an array variable is a pointer to the first element of the array. An array variable can exist on the heap or the stack, and so can the memory that contains its contents. And they can be difference. Your examples are `int` arrays, so you can consider the array variable to be an `int*`.

There are two differences between `int *pointerArray = new int[10];` and `int array[10];`:

The first difference is that the memory that contains the contents of the  first array is allocated on the *heap*. The second array is more tricky. If `array` is a local variable in a function then its contents are allocated on the stack, but if it is a member variable of a class then its contents are allocated wherever the containing object is allocated (heap or stack).

The second difference is that, as you've realised, the first array is dynamic: its size can be determined at run-time. The second array is fixed: the compiler must be able to determine its size at compile time.

Answer (score 2):

First, I'd look for some other place to learn C++.  The page you cite is
very confusing, and has little to do with the way one actually programs
in C++.  In C++, most of the time, you'd use `std::vector` for an array,
not the complex solutions proposed on the page you cite.  In practice,
you never use `operator new[]` (an array `new`).

In fact, `std::vector` is in some ways more like `ArrayList` than simple
arrays in Java; unlike an array in Java, you can simply grow the vector
by inserting elements into it, preferrably at the end.  And it supports
iterators, although C++ iterators are considerably different than Java
iterators.  On the other hand, you can access it using the `[]`
operator, like a normal array.

The arrays described on the page you cite are usually called C style
arrays.  In C++, their use is mostly limited to objects with static
lifetime, although they do occasionally appear in classes.  In any case, they are never allocated dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

The main difference is that some operations that are allowed on pointers are not allowed on arrays.

Answer (score 0):

On the one hand:

```
int ar[10];
```

is using memory allocated on the stack. You can think of it also locally available and while it is possible to pass a pointer / reference to otehr functions, the memory will be freed as soon as it goes out of scope (in your example at the end of the main method but that's usually not the case).

On the other hand:

```
int ar* = new int[10];
```

allocates the memory for the array on the heap. It is available until your whole program exits or it is deleted using

```
delete[] ar;
```

note, that for delete you need the "[]" if and only if the corresponding new has had them, too.

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference but not in the area that you point to. `*pointerArray` will point to the beginning of a block of memory of size 10 bytes. So will `array`. The only difference will be where it is stored in memory. `pointerArray` is dynamically assigned memory (at `run-time`) and hence will go on the heap, while `array[10]` will be allocated at `compile-time` and will go to the stack.

Answer (score 0):

It is true that you can get most of array functionality by using a pointer to its first element. But compiler knows that a static array is composed of several elements and the most notable difference is the result of the `sizeof` operator.

`sizeof(pointerArray) = sizeof int*`

`sizeof(array) = 10 * sizeof int`