# Why do dynamic and static arrays have different typenames? (C++)

Tags: c++, arrays, typename

Trying to debug a program I stumbled upon something interesting and was wondering the implications of this.

I noticed that when defining an array dynamically or statically that I get different typenames. For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
int main()
{
   int a[10];
   int *b = new int[10];
   int c[5][10];
   int **d = new int*[5];
   for ( size_t i = 0; i < 5; ++i )
      d[i] = new int[10];
   std::cout << typeid(a).name() << std::endl;
   std::cout << typeid(b).name() << std::endl;
   std::cout << typeid(c).name() << std::endl;
   std::cout << typeid(d).name() << std::endl;
   return 0;
}
```

I get the outputs

```
A10_i
Pi
A5_A10_i
PPi
```

I am having problems writing `PPi` data into hdf5 format but am curious as to why these types are different and in what way they differ.

Comment: Well, `b` and `d` aren't arrays, they are pointers (to the first element of heap-allocated arrays) - as you can gather from the output: "A" is for array, "P" is for pointer.

Comment: Arrays have their own type in C++. Probably you're confused because they decay to a pointer when passed as parameters to a function.

Comment: I guess that is where the confusion is. For the majority of my use of them they have acted the same. I understand that it is `Pointer int` but did not realize that they do act differently. Which I am curious about.

Comment: related/dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6122091/whats-the-difference-pointer-to-an-array-vs-regular-array

Comment: One of the most noticeable differences is `sizeof`. `sizeof(pointer)` will give you the size of an address, usually 4 or 8 bytes regardless of what's pointed at. `sizeof(array)` will give you the size of the whole array. For `uint32_t array[10]`, `sizeof(array)` better be 40 (4 * 10).

Answer (score 3):

There's not really things like *static* or *dynamic* arrays. There are *static storage allocation*, *dynamic storage allocation* and *pointers*. Each of these have their own types. *static storage allocation* will result in it's own type that is fixed about the size.

As a general rule a **pointer** looses the information that it points to an array and what the size was.
Be it declared as raw array (e.g. `int arr[13]; int* p = arr;`) or dynamically allocated with `new []` (e.g. `int* p = new int[13];`).