# How to swap two __m128i variables in C++03 given its an opaque type and an array?

Tags: c++, swap, intrinsics, c++03, sunstudio

What is the best practice for swapping `__m128i` variables?

The background is a [compile error under Sun Studio 12.2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38417190/608639), which is a C++03 compiler. `__m128i` is an opaque type used with MMX and SSE instructions, and its usually and `unsigned long long[2]`. C++03 does not provide the support for swapping arrays, and `std:swap(__m128i a, __m128i b)` fails under the compiler.

---

Here are some related questions that don't quite hit the mark. They don't apply because `std::vector` is not available.

- [How can we swap 2 arrays in constant complexity or O(1)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26312551)
- [Is it possible to swap arrays of structs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9242984)
- [C++03 moving a vector into a class member through constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25507858)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't sound like a best-practices issue; it sounds like you need a workaround for a seriously broken implementation of intrinsics.  If `__m128i tmp = a;` doesn't compile, that's pretty bad.

---

If you're going to write a custom swap function, keep it simple.  `__m128i` is a POD type that fits in a single vector register.  Don't do anything that will encourage the compiler to spill it to memory.  Some compilers will generate really horrible code even for a trivial test-case, and even gcc/clang might trip over a memcpy as part of optimizing a big complicated function.

Since the compiler is choking on the constructor, just declare a tmp variable with a normal initializer, and use `=` assignment to do the copying.  That always works efficiently in any compiler that supports `__m128i`, and is a common pattern.

Plain assignment to/from values in memory works like `_mm_store_si128` / `_mm_load_si128`: i.e. [`movdqa` aligned stores/loads](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/MOVDQA.html) that will fault if used on unaligned addresses.  (Of course, optimization can result in loads getting folded into memory operands to another vector instruction, or stores not happening at all.)

```
// alternate names: assignment_swap
// or swap128, but then the name doesn't fit for __m256i...

// __m128i t(a) errors, so just use simple initializers / assignment
template<class T>
void vecswap(T& a, T& b) {
    // T t = a;     // Apparently SunCC even choked on this
    T t;
    t = a;
    a = b;
    b = t;
}
```

Test cases: optimal code even with a crusty compiler like ICC13 which does a terrible job with the memcpy version.  asm output from the [Godbolt compiler explorer, with icc13 `-O3`](http://gcc.godbolt.org/#compilers:!((compiler:icc1301,options:'-std%3Dc%2B%2B03+-Wall+-Wextra+-O3+-fno-verbose-asm',sourcez:MQSwdgxgNgrgJgUwAQB4QFt3gC4CdwB0AFgHwBQZA9JUgPq3oCMATABwhLYAUAhgJRIEuXAHtcAZwA0ScSKQArGOOxIlycRgAOUZOBDYQPKCABeQ8Uho9xGgOZh0CMNjLYE6bTzcpo1iwBVyADcREDgkIIQIcQB3Hk0ufwAyJB5pZKQAIwEAbzIkAqR/TiQAXlSAbnzCnjKsqsKsuuwqgF8qGk0RN2dDKFSoN1wwL2QRx3EALlSbEHtHZ1pY%2BI6kMRk4zRZWaUyYFWwiJ04jpHHkOBEEcTAAchUAM30kB/X6dGYAVgA2EAJ/ihkd7bDhuZS0XAIbAwYbMMBwLjAtgcAAe0iR7CQAE9ctUCpFopsuGjsXwGoVIdDhkgUW0KBjQddsBCoTCwIxlIiGCCaejucjSUg8o0CcsEiSceSCpS2di6WQQmFOEyGO4uUwBQAqEkMpCanFCvERKJirja6T6slkdpA/mYsHMxzoSG2dU8nV2jiWw0ik1EkmWqVIGXU2nWwEdahR6NRjbxJAxfREJBOiCaLGpeFIIgiTS6FS2KEWXMGLBmcI8OJYsigSCwRCoaJ4cC2ciudyeby%2BGxFYKhcJO00ZNJFFLZMjCwrFFpG5RwSaTVPprhJbDSJIjjRmEQPLjYPhWxpzhdLrErkdJTLSLcIHd7g9B4%2BL9xps%2BX9drmSmW%2B7/dWm26iGYBwnAqroK%2BboCh6GqYgak4FIO/rSJKRpATS8qAaywwco6L7Lrq0E8nBRqIfExLIYeFJYWAcrhgq/bKuCTpgRBurmnQnp6sRjSkQk7GBnRuoOmBLosfhnGEVq3GFLx5FcZR0rUeh4ZAAAA)),filterAsm:(commentOnly:!t,directives:!t,intel:!t,labels:!t),version:3)

```
__m128i test_return2nd(__m128i x, __m128i y) {
    vecswap(x, y);
    return x;
}

    movdqa    xmm0, xmm1
    ret                    # returning the 2nd arg, which was in xmm1


__m128i test_return1st(__m128i x, __m128i y) {
    vecswap(x, y);
    return y;
}

    ret                   # returning the first arg, already in xmm0
```

With memswap, you get something like

```
return1st_memcpy(__m128i, __m128i):        ## ICC13 -O3
    movdqa    XMMWORD PTR [-56+rsp], xmm0
    movdqa    XMMWORD PTR [-40+rsp], xmm1    # spill both
    movaps    xmm2, XMMWORD PTR [-56+rsp]    # reload x
    movaps    XMMWORD PTR [-24+rsp], xmm2    # copy x to tmp
    movaps    xmm0, XMMWORD PTR [-40+rsp]    # reload y
    movaps    XMMWORD PTR [-56+rsp], xmm0    # copy y to x
    movaps    xmm0, XMMWORD PTR [-24+rsp]    # reload tmp
    movaps    XMMWORD PTR [-40+rsp], xmm0    # copy tmp to y
    movdqa    xmm0, XMMWORD PTR [-40+rsp]    # reload y
    ret                                      # return y
```

This is pretty much the absolute maximum amount of spilling/reloading you could imagine to swap two registers, because icc13 doesn't optimize between the inlined `memcpy`s at all, or even remember what is left in a register.

---

#### Swapping values already in memory

Even gcc makes worse code with the memcpy version.  It does the copy with 64bit integer loads/stores instead of a 128bit vector load/store.  This is terrible if you're about to load the vector (store-forwarding stall), and otherwise is just bad (more uops to do the same work).

```
// the memcpy version of this compiles badly
void test_mem(__m128i *x, __m128i *y) {
    vecswap(*x, *y);
}
    # gcc 5.3 and ICC13 make the same code here, since it's easy to optimize
    movdqa  xmm0, XMMWORD PTR [rdi]
    movdqa  xmm1, XMMWORD PTR [rsi]
    movaps  XMMWORD PTR [rdi], xmm1
    movaps  XMMWORD PTR [rsi], xmm0
    ret

// gcc 5.3 with memswap instead of vecswap.  ICC13 is similar
test_mem_memcpy(long long __vector(2)*, long long __vector(2)*):
    mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rdi]
    mov     rdx, QWORD PTR [rdi+8]
    mov     r9, QWORD PTR [rsi]
    mov     r10, QWORD PTR [rsi+8]
    mov     QWORD PTR [rdi], r9
    mov     QWORD PTR [rdi+8], r10
    mov     QWORD PTR [rsi], rax
    mov     QWORD PTR [rsi+8], rdx
    ret
```

Comment: Thanks Peter, That's the kind of insight I was looking for. The last open question: should I provide a [`std::swap` specialization for `__m128i`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11562), or simply leave it as a stand alone function?

Comment: @jww:   It's probably best to just call it `vecswap`, so you can use it on derived types.  (e.g. [Agner Fog's Vector Class Library wrappers like `Vec4i`](http://www.agner.org/optimize/#vectorclass)).  If you did specialize, you'd probably want to do it for `__m128i`, `__m128d`, `__m128`, `__m256*`, `__m512*`, and any other SIMD types for other architectures.  (ARM NEON or w/e), and then it's pretty bulky.  I'd be happier just using a different function which I'm sure is always light-weight and optimizes well.  If you're sure you only need a few types, worth considering a specialisation though.

Comment: Believe it or not, this resulted in the original compile problem under SunCC: `T t = a; a = b; b = t;`. I had to `T t; t=a, a=b, b=t;` to get the compiler to stop trying to initialize it.

Comment: @jww: Wow, that compiler is going to choke on a lot of code, then.  I assume it chokes on `__m128i v = _mm_add_epi32(a,b);` as well?  For most code, I think I'd just consider it broken rather than rewrite any significant amount of code for its benefit.

Comment: @PeterCordes How is `vecswap()` different from `std::swap()`?

Comment: @Leon: IDK, I don't have SunCC.  Maybe it's identical, since jww had to modify my code to avoid the error, see 2 comments ago.  I updated the code in my answer, which I should have done 3 hours ago.

Answer (score 2):

swap via `memcpy`?

```
#include <emmintrin.h>
#include <cstring>

template<class T>
void memswap(T& a, T& b)
{
    T t;
    std::memcpy(&t, &a, sizeof(t));
    std::memcpy(&a, &b, sizeof(t));
    std::memcpy(&b, &t, sizeof(t));
}

int main() {
    __m128i x;
    __m128i y;
    memswap(x, y);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you're going to write a custom swap function, just use assignment by value because that's optimal for `__m128i` values.  gcc does manage to optimize away the memcpy and keep values in registers (with a test function that takes two `__m128i` args and returns a `__m128i`), [but ICC13 doesn't](https://godbolt.org/g/q0xYxo).  Simple assignment is much less likely to have a negative impact on optimization.  ICC13 has no problem with it, for example.

Comment: Even gcc can trip up when using `memswap` on `__m128i`, if the values are both already in memory.  See my answer.