# Array syntax and pointers in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, malloc

Is my understanding of arrays in C correct?
Arrays are nothing more than a syntactic convenience such that, for instance, when you declare in your C code an array:

```
type my_array[x];
```

the compiler sees it as something equivalent to:

```
type *my_array = malloc(sizeof(*my_array) * x);
```

with a `free` system call that releases `my_array` once we leave the scope of `my_array`.

Once `my_array` is declared

```
my_array[y];
```

is nothing more but:

```
*(my_array + y)
```

---

Transposing this to character strings; I was also wondering what was happening behind the curtain with

```
char *my_string = "Hello"
```

and

```
my_string = "Hello"
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10186765/char-array-vs-char-pointer-in-c

Comment: Not exactly. When you do `type my_array[x]`, the compiler does see it as an array and even knows that, at compile time, `sizeof(my_array)` is `x * sizeof(type)`, but that is not the case if you declare `type *my_array = malloc(x * sizeof(type))`. In that case, `sizeof(my_array)` is the size of a pointer to type for your compiler.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/660752/pointer-vs-array-in-c-non-trivial-difference

Comment: Don't assume that the C compiler will create `malloc` and `free` calls for you. This would go completely against the goal of this language which is supposed to give you absolute control over the memory you use, especially in constrained environments where malloc might be really expensive. There are other memory storage mechanisms.

Comment: Another difference: the array points to the same address during its lifetime whereas a pointer can be changed.

Comment: [C FAQ: Arrays and Pointers](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/) See specifically 6.2, which is the immediate answer, but not the entire one.

Answer (score 2):

No, an array object is an array object. C has some odd rules that make it *appear* that arrays and pointers are the same thing, or at least very similar, but they very definitely are not.

This declaration:

```
int my_array[100];
```

creates an array object; the object's size is `100 * sizeof (int)`. It does *not* create a pointer object.

There is no `malloc()`, even implicitly. Storage for `my_array` is allocated the same way as storage for any object declared in the same scope.

What may be confusing you is that, in most but not all contexts, an expression of array type is implicitly *converted* to a pointer to the array's first element. (This gives you a pointer value; there's still no pointer object.) This conversion doesn't happen if the array expression is the operand of a unary `&` or `sizeof`. `&my_array` gives you the address of the array, not of some nonexistent pointer obejct. `sizeof my_array` is the size of the entire array (100 * sizeof (int)`), not the size of a pointer.

Also, if you define a function parameter with an array type:

```
void func(int param[]) { ... }
```

it's *adjusted* at compile time to a pointer:

```
void func(int *param) { ... }
```

This isn't a conversion; in that context (and only in that context), `int param[]` really *means* `int *param`.

Also, array indexing:

```
my_array[3] = 42;
```

is defined in terms of pointer arithmetic -- which means that the prefix `my_array` has to be converted to a pointer before you can index into it.

The most important thing to remember is this: Arrays are not pointer. Pointers are not arrays.

Section 6 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www-c.faq.com) explains all this very well.

> Once my_array is declared
>
> `my_array[y];`
>
> is nothing more but :
>
> `*(my_array + y)`

Yes, because `my_array` is converted to a pointer, and the `[]` operator is defined so that `x[y]` means `*(x+y)`.

> Transposing this to character strings; i was also wondering what was
>   happening behind the curtain with
>
> `char *my_string = "Hello"`
>
> and
>
> `my_string = "Hello"`

`"Hello"` is a string literal. It's an expression of type `char[6]`, referring to an anonymous statically allocated array object. If it appears on the RHS of an assignment or initializer, it's converted, like any array expression, to a pointer. The first line initializes `my_string` so it points to the first character of `"Hello"`. The second is a pointer assignment that does the same thing.

So what about this?

```
char str[] = "Hello";
```

This is the third context in which array-to-pointer conversion doesn't happen. `str` takes its size from the size of the string literal, and the array is copied to `str`. It's the same as:

```
char str[] = { 'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0' };
```

Answer (score 1):

No!

`type array[n]` is a variable stored on stack

`type *array` is a pointer variable stored on the stack too. But after `array = malloc(sizeof(*array) * n);` it'll point to some data on the heap

Answer (score 0):

If it walks like a duck, swims like a duck and flies like a duck, then it is a duck.

So, let's see. Arrays and pointers have some common attributes as you correctly described, however, you can see there are some differences. Read more [here](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/Difference_between_pointers_and_arrays_in_C).