# Difference between char **p,char *p[],char p[][]

Tags: c

```
char *p = "some string"
```

creates a pointer p pointing to a block containing the string.

```
char p[] = "some string"
```

creates a character array and with literals in it.

And the first one is a constant declaration.Is it the same of two-dimensional arrays?

what is the difference between

```
char **p,char *p[],char p[][].
```

I read a bit about this that char **p creates an array of pointers so it has an overhead compared to `char p[][]` for storing the pointer values.

the first two declarations create constant arrays.i did not get any run time error when i tried to modify the contents of `argv` in `main(int argc,char **argv)`. Is it because they are declared in function prototype?

Comment: This stuff is incredibly confusing.  It's first important to understand that the term "creates" must be used with great caution -- "declares" is *not* the same as "creates".

Comment: Read section 6 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com/).

Comment: by "creates" i mean declares and initializes.or "defines".

Comment: @KeithThompson that's a nice link.i am going through it.

Comment: This has already been discussed countless times. Please do some research before asking.

Comment: Pay particular attention to the fact that `char foo[]` has a different meaning as an object declaration and as a parameter declaration.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C: differences between char pointer and array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335786/c-differences-between-char-pointer-and-array) and [C pointer to array/array of pointers disambiguation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/859634/c-pointer-to-array-array-of-pointers-disambiguation) and [Pointer vs array in C, non-trivial difference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/660752/pointer-vs-array-in-c-non-trivial-difference).

Comment: Just for the sake of completeness there's also `char (*p)[]` which is a pointer to array of char.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### Normal Declarations (Not Function Parameters)

`char **p;` declares a pointer to a pointer to `char`. It reserves space for the pointer. It does not reserve any space for the pointed-to pointers or any `char`.

`char *p[N];` declares an array of *N* pointers to `char`. It reserves space for *N* pointers. It does not reserve any space for any `char`. `N` must be provided explicitly or, in a definition with initializers, implicitly by letting the compiler count the initializers.

`char p[M][N];` declares an array of *M* arrays of *N* `char`. It reserves space for *M*•*N* `char`. There are no pointers involved. `N` must be provided explicitly. `M` must be provided explicitly or, in a definition with initializers, implicitly by letting the compiler count the initializers.

### Declarations in Function Parameters

`char **p` declares a pointer to a pointer to `char`. When the function is called, space is provided for that pointer (typically on a stack or in a processor register). No space is reserved for the pointed-to-pointers or any `char`.

`char *p[N]` is adjusted to be `char **p`, so it is the same as above. The value of `N` is ignored, and `N` may be absent. (Some compilers may evaluate `N`, so, if it is an expression with side effects, such as `printf("Hello, world.\n")`, these effects may occur when the function is called. The C standard is unclear on this.)

`char p[M][N]` is adjusted to be `char (*p)[N]`, so it is a pointer to an array of *N* `char`. The value of `M` is ignored, and `M` may be absent. `N` must be provided. When the function is called, space is provided for the pointer (typically on a stack or in a processor register). No space is reserved for the array of *N* `char`.

### argv

`argv` is created by the special software that calls `main`. It is filled with data that the software obtains from the “environment”. You are allowed to modify the `char` data in it.

In your definition `char *p = "some string";`, you are not permitted to modify the data that `p` points to because the C standard says that characters in a string literal may not be modified. (Technically, what it says is that it does not define the behavior if you try.) In this definition, `p` is not an array; it is a pointer to the first `char` in an array, and those `char` are inside a string literal, and you are not permitted to modify the contents of a string literal.

In your definition `char p[] = "some string";`, you may modify the contents of `p`. They are not a string literal. In this case, the string literal effectively does not exist at run-time; it is only something used to specify how the array `p` is initialized. Once `p` is initialized, you may modify it.

The data set up for `argv` is set up in a way that allows you to modify it (because the C standard specifies this).

Comment: I think that's the clearest discussion of this mess I've ever read.

Comment: just an addition n in the second case (char *p[N]) and m in the third case (char p[M][N]) need not be provided when we are initializing the array with some values.

Answer (score 6):

Some more differences description looking it from memory addressing view as follows,

I. `char **p;` `p` is double pointer of type `char`

Declaration:

```
char a = 'g';
char *b = &a;
char **p = &b;
```

```
   p                    b                    a     
+------+             +------+             +------+
|      |             |      |             |      |              
|0x2000|------------>|0x1000|------------>|   g  | 
|      |             |      |             |      |
+------+             +------+             +------+
 0x3000               0x2000               0x1000
Figure 1: Typical memory layout assumption
```

In above declaration, `a` is `char` type containing a character `g`. Pointer `b` contains the address of an existing character variable `a`. Now `b` is address `0x1000` and `*b` is character `g`. Finally address of `b` is assigned to `p`, therefore `a` is a character variable, `b` is pointer and `p` is pointer to pointer. Which implies `a` contains value, `b` contains address and `p` contains address of address as shown below in the diagram.

Here, `sizeof(p) = sizeof(char *)` on respective system;

II. `char *p[M];` `p` is array of strings

Declaration:

```
char *p[] = {"Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday"};
```

```
      p
   +------+  
   | p[0] |       +----------+
0  | 0x100|------>| Monday\0 |              
   |      |       +----------+
   |------|       0x100
   | p[1] |       +-----------+
1  | 0x200|------>| Tuesday\0 |
   |      |       +-----------+
   |------|       0x200
   | p[2] |       +-------------+
2  | 0x300|------>| Wednesday\0 |
   |      |       +-------------+ 
   +------+       0x300
Figure 2: Typical memory layout assumption
```

In this declaration, `p` is array of 3 pointers of type `char`. Implies array `p` can hold 3 strings. Each string `(Monday, Tuesday & Wednesday)` is located some where in memory `(0x100, 0x200 & 0x300)`, there addresses are in array `p` as `(p[0], p[1] & p[2])` respectively. Hence it is array of pointers.

Notes: `char *p[3];`

```
1. p[0], p[1] & p[2] are addresses of strings of type `char *`.
2. p, p+1 & p+2 are address of address with type being `char **`.
3. Accessing elements is through, p[i][j] is char; p[i] is char *; & p is char **
```

Here `sizeof(p) = Number of char array * sizeof(char *)`

III. `char p[M][N];` `p` is array of fixed length strings with dimensions as `M x N`

Declaration:

```
char p[][10] = {Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday};
```

```
  p  0x1 2 3 4 5 6 7  8  9  10
    +-------------------------+
 0  | M  o n d a y \0 \0 \0 \0|     
 1  | T  u e s d a  y \0 \0 \0| 
 2  | W  e d n e s  d  a  y \0|
    +-------------------------+
 Figure 3: Typical memory layout assumption
```

In this case array `p` contain 3 strings each containing 10 characters. Form the memory layout we can say `p` is a two dimensional array of characters with size `MxN`, which is `3x10` in our example. This is useful for representing strings of equal length since there is a possibility of memory wastage when strings contains lesser than 10 characters compared to declaration `char *p[]`, which has no memory wastage because string length is not specified and it is useful for representing strings of unequal length.

Accessing elements is similar as above case, `p[M]` is M'th string & p[M][N] is N'th character of M'th string. 
Here `sizeof(p) = (M rows * N columns) * sizeof(char)` of two dimensional array;

Comment: thanks!that was a very detailed explanation.i just want to confirm one more thing.can we change the individual characters in an array of character pointers? here is the code http://codepad.org/2vyx2IbY.it gave me a seg fault on emacs

Comment: @programer8 Answer is No. In your code `p[i]` & `f` are pointing to constant string literals which cannot be modified assigning `p[i][j] = 'j'` & `f[i] = 'j'` respectively. Look at this [code](http://codepad.org/U8S3Velk) which tells a 2D array & a character array indeed allows you to modify the characters.

Answer (score 0):

- `a` in `char* a` is pointer to array of chars, `a` can be modified.
- `b` in `char b[]` is array of chars.  `b` cannot be modified.

They are sort of compatible -  `b` can automatically *decay* to `a` in assignments and expressions, but not other way around.

When you use `char** p`, `char* p[]` and `char p[][]` it is very similar situation, just more levels of indirection.

Comment: `char p[][]` is illegal, for obvious reasons.  It has to be something like `char p[][6]`.

Comment: @DietrichEpp i noticed that too.we have to mention second dimension while passing values to a function.But i was talking about command line arguments.

Comment: @programer8: Command line arguments?  What does that have to do with it?  `char p[][]` is always illegal.