# What's the difference between `typeof(array)` vs `typeof(*array) *`

Tags: c, gcc, typeof

To be more specific, I'm struggling to comprehend why this fails in compilation:

```
 int array[] = {4, 3, 2, 1};
 typeof(array) __array_copy = (array);
```

with the error being:

```
main.c: In function 'test_map':
main.c:113: error: invalid initializer
```

However this works:

```
 int array[] = {4, 3, 2, 1};
 typeof(*array) *__array_copy = (array);
```

What exactly is the difference between `typeof(array)` vs `typeof(*array) *`?

Comment: The former is an array, the latter is a pointer. You can't initialize an array with another array (for some reason, the C standard committee thought that it's a good idea, I think it's not). You can, however, initialize a pointer with a pointer, which is formed by the array decaying into a pointer to its first element. And before you ask it: **No, an array is not just a pointer.** (and `__array_copy` is **not** a copy of the original array. It isn't even correct code -- identifiers starting with a double underscore are reserved for the implementation, so this code has undefined behavior.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pointer vs array in C, non-trivial difference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/660752/pointer-vs-array-in-c-non-trivial-difference)

Comment: @user3477950, thanks for the answer, I think that explains it adequately.  Mind reposting it as an "answer" rather than a comment so I can accept it?

Comment: Since this is actually a duplicate, I'd rather not post a separate answer.

Comment: @SteveCox it's a GNU extension to C.

Comment: @SteveCox, It's a GCC extension https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Typeof.html

Comment: then please mark this gcc, not just C